# How do I view the webcontent of a maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have imported a Maven project into Eclipse. I have also run the command `mvn jetty:run` to check that the project works.

The files that used to be under the `MyProject/WebContent` directory are now under `MyProject/src/main/webapp/`. I can see them on the file system, but not in eclipse. How do I view and edit these files in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The `src/main/webapp` folder is not a `source folder` in eclipse terminology, so it's not listed among `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources` etc. This is correct, because it's not a source folder for maven, either (just for the war plugin)

So you have to expand the `src` folder manually in Eclipse:

[image: src/main/webapp]

However, you can then right-click the folder and select `Build Path > Use as Source Folder`. (Adding it as a source folder in Eclipse won't change your maven setup)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to switch project facet in eclipse to web-project... Can't check it right now -so it's just assumption.